# Postgres - i want to return a function to return different query result from different table?

Tags: postgresql

I want to return a function to return different query result from different table, will it possible?

```
 RETURNS SETOF RECORD
  AS $$
 
  sql = FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s', view_name, where_cls);

  -- EXECUTE sql;
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and your function does it. Now what is your real question?

Comment: I assume that he wants that function returns  different columns depending on the table queried. Then its not possible i think.

Comment: Yes, function to return different columns based on table queried, table will be passed as param. thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.